# FreeBSD pkg_create how to

Tags: shell, package, freebsd

I want to create a FreeBSD binary package containing some software. All I'm interested in doing is saying

"Some files in directory X need to go in directory Y " preserving the directory hierarchy beneath it. I can specify every file in the packing list easily if necessary.

However this seems awfully difficult to achieve, as I cannot find the combination of the -s, -S @cwd and @srcdir parameters which does what I want. It either looks in directory Y for the files (which doesn't exist on the build system), or packages the files to go in directory X, which is also not what I want.

Before you answer "just create a port", I'm not REMOTELY interested in creating a "port". A "port" is nothing whatsoever to do with what we're doing. It's not a package for distribution by third parties, nor a cross-platform application intended for source distirbution BY third parties.

All I want to do is make a binary package to install some files in a specified place in the filesystem. Is that too hard?

This is under FreeBSD 7.3.

Comment: Did you ever find a working solution? I'm in a similar spot, but I do intend to make a redistributable package. However I don't wish to create a port since I already have the binaries. Hence "Make package" does not really do what I want.

Answer (score 4):

Just create a package directly. Either with pkg_create (and generating or piping in a 'find' style pkg list; or alternatively create a trivial package (Fetch something like pub/FreeBSD/ports/amd64/packages-6.3-release/Allwidentd-1.03_1.tbz as a simple example) consisting of a directory with:

```
+CONTENTS
      see example or man page
+COMMENT
      foo
+DESC
      foo
+MTREE_DIRS
      /set type=dir uname=root gname=wheel mode=0755
      .
         bin
         ..
         etc
         ..
      ..
```

and then:

```
your files..
```

the later relative to /usr/local. Just take a package like above as to what goes in there. Above is then simply 'tar & gz'-ed up - and presto - a pacakge.

Dw.